# What are some conferences for publishing papers on graph convolutional networks?

Tags: reference-request, research, geometric-deep-learning, academia, graph-neural-networks

What are some conferences for publishing papers on graph convolutional networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on past publications, here are some journals and conferences where you can possibly publish or present a research paper on geometric deep learning or graph neural networks

- [Neural Information Processing Systems (NIPS)](https://nips.cc/)
- [International Conference on Learning Representations (ICLR)](https://iclr.cc/)
- [Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)](http://cvpr2020.thecvf.com/)
- [International Conference on Machine Learning (ICML)](https://icml.cc/)

The website http://geometricdeeplearning.com/ also provides some information about the topic and links you to several workshops, papers, and tutorials.

Here are some links to some of the past workshops on GDL.

- [Representation Learning on Graphs and Manifolds](https://iclr.cc/Conferences/2019/Schedule?showEvent=631) (and [the related homepage](https://rlgm.github.io/))
- [Workshop IV: Deep Geometric Learning of Big Data and Applications](https://www.ipam.ucla.edu/programs/workshops/workshop-iv-deep-geometric-learning-of-big-data-and-applications/)
- [Geometric Deep Learning on Graphs and Manifolds](https://nips.cc/Conferences/2017/Schedule?showEvent=8735).